# Edit Whatsapp contact name in Samsung Galaxy S3 Neo?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, contacts, whatsapp-messenger

I wrongly saved one of my friend's name. Later renamed it with original name but when I searched contacts in WhatsApp I saw his name is still old one. I can't find a way to change name. I tried to edit via mobile contacts, but edit button in WhatsApp contact is disable. How to change WhatsApp contact that name in Samsung Galaxy S3 Neo?

[image: screenshot] [image: screenshot]
<sup>Screenshots (click images for larger variants)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow these steps:

- Rename the contact in your phone book and save.
- Go to `Settings > Account > whatsapp > sync now` (or any similar option)

Most likely, your contact is not synced after you renamed!

Answer (score 1):

This may work :

1. Save your friend's number (copy & paste into a note taking app or write it on paper or just remember it).
2. Delete your friend's number.
3. Add new contact with the name you want and enter your friends number.

Comment: +1 Nice idea. I didn't think in this simple way :) I changed his whatsapp contacts name now :) but my doubt is why can't we change the name without deleting the contact?

Answer (score 1):

WhatsApp seems to create a **read-only version of the contact on many phones**, so if simply changing the contact's name in your contacts app doesn't work, you might have to:

1. Delete the contact
2. Create a new one with the updated name.

Answer (score 1):

Can't it be done by synchronisation of contact over whatsapp contact..
I mean editing contact in phone or sim card and sync to whatsapp then whatsapp replace the old contact and shows the new one.

Answer (score 0):

It is to be done from inside Whatsapp and is simple.
1. Open Whatsapp
2. Tap Add Contact icon at the right bottom
3. Select New Contact
4. Select the choice of phone or SIM
5. Enter the Name
6. Enter the phone number
7. Save.